# Which entity rxtractor should use? Rasa

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

In my training data, I want to extract the following values from user input.

`phone number,location,reference_number`. So which entity extractor I need to use?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should go with Duckling entity extractor. It can extract numbers, locations, etc. However if you are running this you have to run it in a separately and connect it through *config.yml* file.

Refer [Rasa components](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/components/#ducklinghttpextractor) and [forum](https://forum.rasa.com/t/how-to-use-duckling-in-pipeline/91) for more information